# File not Found Exception When Using .getInputStream()

Tags: android

Trying to use the following Code to download a remote hosted .apk file.

```
package com.wireless.wmaa;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class UpdateApp extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
private Context context;
public void setContext(Context contextf){
    context = contextf;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
      try {
            URL url = new URL(arg0[0]);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            String PATH = "/sdcard/Download/";
            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, "Wireless.apk");
            if(outputFile.exists()){
                outputFile.delete();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();


            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new                File("/sdcard/Download/Wireless.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without this flag     android returned a intent error!
            context.startActivity(intent);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("UpdateAPP", "Update error! " + e.getMessage());
        }
    return null;
}}
```

And Here is the Code to start the Task:

```
UpdateApp myApp = new UpdateApp();
myApp.setContext(getApplicationContext());
myApp.execute("http://some.domain.com/someSite/some.apk");
```

Able to connect but when trying to use the InputStream throws a file not found exception. I can browse to the file from the Android Default Browser and I am prompted to download the file which is the same functionality I would like in my App. Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wireless.wmaa"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
                                         >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SelectServer" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
            </intent-filter>"
            </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UpdateApp"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >  
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".WirelessActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >  
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being an Issue with IIS. Once I moved my .apk to my apache webserver had no issues...

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong at this line `File outputFile = new File(file, "Wireless.apk");`

just changed it as follows,

```
File outputFile = new File( PATH + "Wireless.apk");
```

also change following code

```
if(outputFile.exists())
{
     outputFile.delete();
}
else  // Add Else part, it is missing in your code
{
     outputFile.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: Made the change you suggested and still receiving same result. I don't believe my original code was wrong at the point because File has more than just a constructor for type string. File has a constructor where you pass it a File and a String. Which is what I was using prior to your suggestion, both ways are acceptable. File (File dir, String name) 
Since: API Level 1 
Constructs a new file using the specified directory and name.

Parameters
dir  the directory where the file is stored. 
name  the file's name.

Comment: The line that is throwing the exception InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

Comment: yeah, I see where you are going but still throwing the exception when I attempt to pull an inputstream from my connection variable.

Comment: wait a min, what is the value of your URL ?

Comment: Well I don't want to give the actual value of the URL, but I know through debugging that the String I pass here    myApp.execute("http://some.domain.com/someSite/some.apk"); Makes it into my task and I am able to connect to it. And it also works in the browser.

Comment: no problem with that, rest all the code looks fine, i cant understand, why you are getting this error :(

Comment: Well the site that it is going to is hosted in IIS 7.5 I don't if this could be causing an issue. All I know is the file is there at the URL I specify and pointing a browser to it will pull the file. Just can't get it to work programmatically.

Comment: are you trying in emulator or in real device ?

Comment: @Adam, do you have proxy settings with firewall ? i think that's why it is accessable in browser but not in emulator or real device.

Comment: Yes there are firewalls in place where the file is being hosted. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use /sdcard/Downloads...this path is different in some devices.
You should use:

```
File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory(); does not always return the path to the external SD card across all hardware types. Especially for devices with multiple SD cards. And I happen to be using one of those types.